update installation ocaml/opam for msvc environment
I've installed ocaml under Windows11 using opam 2.2.1 default way, it works fine. I would try the msvc toolchain but unsure about the right way to do it. I'got VS 2022 community edition, reading ocaml pages I figure that "opam install system-MSVC" should be the first step but, don't know how to create the new switch.
https://ocaml.org/docs/ocaml-on-windows
I've installed and tested default environment with opam/dune and all works fine.
I've read about some issues about MSVC toolchain, but I'm unsure about it.
I'm interested in ocaml/win32/c++ application developing, so the use of microsoft c compiler and linker seem a good way.
After some cleanup and test, I got the point.
It seems that the mingw64 and the MSVC switch cannot be used in the same opam/ocaml installation.
Thats what "opam install system-msvc" says
The following actions will be performed:
=== remove 5 packages

remove    base-domains        base            [conflicts with ocaml]
remove    base-nnp            base            [uses base-domains]
remove    host-system-mingw   1
remove    ocaml-env-mingw64   1
remove    system-mingw        1               [conflicts with system-msvc]
=== downgrade 2 packages
downgrade ocaml               5.2.0 to 4.14.2 [uses ocaml-base-compiler]
downgrade ocaml-base-compiler 5.2.0 to 4.14.2 [uses system-msvc]
=== recompile 1 package
recompile ocaml-config        3               [uses ocaml-base-compiler]
=== install 5 packages
install   conf-msvc64         1               [required by ocaml-env-msvc64]
install   host-system-msvc    1
install   msvs-detect         0.7.0           [required by conf-msvc64]
install   ocaml-env-msvc64    1               [required by system-msvc]
install   system-msvc         1

And it works.
With the OCAML.5.3 release the MSVC system should be available.

In the menu on the left-hand side of the page you refer to, right above the selected page, there is one that is titled "Introduction to OPAM switches". Does that page answer your question?

That page explain how to select the ocaml compiler and the library used, but i've not understood how to change the c compiler and linker from cygwin to microsoft.

That's what the command you mention as the first step does, is it not?

I don't know, that is what i'm asking for. I'm afraid that trying this can mess up the opam installation.

What happens if you try?

Opam download some packages. Remove some other, due to conflicts betwren mingw and mscv environment, and recompile more than 60 files. Unfortunately it ends with an error. And reinstalling with system-mingw ends with the same error type. Can't find stdlib.

Can you update the question with the exact steps and error message you get? That would make it more focused and easier to answer I think: I don't use windows, so I won't be able to help much more either way, but it'll be easier for others.
